# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/dwilson2/public_html/WBG410/reviews.php on line 20

Tags: php, parse-error

I need some help finding the issue with this code.   Line 20 is just underneath `$row` comment. I have looked this code over with someone else and we cannot figure out what to do. The code is supposed to end up showing three values, and I have been unable to test the code due to this error. I have added a comment on line 20 to make it easier to find.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dwilson2_410wrt";
$password = "3275626s";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name, id, comment FROM review";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " $row["comment"]
} // this is line 20
}


$conn->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Gaming Products Site</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code? I know it must be missing something but I cannot find out what. Like I said before, there is a comment on line 20 to make it easier to find. If I need to add more code I will attempt to do so.

Comment: syntax errors are off-topic

Comment: tip, it's not on line 20. don't believe everything PHP says

Comment: Tip: it's less than a full one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- line 20 is the correct line, it's complaining there is a } there instead of a ;

Comment: @AndrewSmith `} // this is line 20` look one line up

Comment: The actual error Andrew, may I call you Andrew, is the line just before the `}`

Comment: Did you read the error? `EXPECTING ;`... your echo line has no `;`.

Comment: The error is that it's expecting a ; but receives a } instead. Placing a ; on line 20 would still be syntactically correct

Comment: True, but you *really* wouldn't do that, would you Andrew?

Comment: ah ok... so I'm wrong then. I'll go find my dog now. *pass the popcorn*

Comment: I wouldn't. I'm just pointing out that the error is on line 20 as that is the first point in which the syntax fails

Comment: machine error - line 20. Human error - line 19

Comment: It fails there because it runs into something unexpected. When that happens we all generally look just before what was unexpected which in this case happens to be one line up. We're splitting hairs for the sake of argument Andrew. Have a pleasant evening.

Comment: @JayBlanchard that was the point I was trying to make. The syntax becomes unreadable on line 20 so you have to look at the first human readable character before that for what is wrong. The parser isn't lying

Answer (score 1):

On this line (line 19)

```
echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["comment"]
```

You need to end the line with a semicolon, otherwise PHP will just assume everything after it is just part of the `echo`.